# Verdana vs Arial - How can I set the font sizes in CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I want to use the following font:

```
font-family: Verdana; font-size: 0.85em
```

However I'm concerned that it may not be available on all machines. So here's my substitute. The problem is that the two fonts are not the same size so I need to set like this:

```
font-family: arial; font-size: 1em
```

Which makes it a problem when setting

```
font-family: Verdana, Arial
```

Any suggestions on what I could do? Is Verdana now on almost all machines? Ideally I would like to specify in my body to use a Verdana at 0.85em or an Arial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're save with that. See: http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html

Comment: Yes but what about Linux? Also if I specify the fonts at the same size then Verdana is much bigger.

Comment: Why be concerned about <1% of the market. There are more people still using IE6 than there are linux users. Go view stats by OS: http://gs.statcounter.com/#os-ww-monthly-201008-201108

Comment: But the IE6 users do have Arial and Verdana. :) And yes, fonts are actually supported by IE6. ;)

Comment: Yes, they're better off (??) than linux users :)

Answer (score 2):

As Diodeus says, you're quite safe using these fonts, because they're widely available. But you could use the CSS 3 [font-size-adjust](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-size-adjust-prop) property. It allows to apply a relative resizing factor when a fall-back font is used instead of the preferred one.

This property is not available in many browsers yet, but it is still a good idea to implement it. Support <strike>will</strike> may be better in the <strike>near</strike> future.

Comment: +1 For actually addressing the technical aspects of the question. :)

Comment: Not so sure anymore about 'near' future. Almost four years later, and only FireFox has implemented and enabled this. In Chrome, you can enable it as an 'experimental feature', and other browsers don't support it at all and don't plan to. [Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com/#feat=font-size-adjust).

Answer (score 0):

According to this survey:

http://www.codestyle.org/css/font-family/sampler-CombinedResultsFull.shtml

Verdana has a near 100% rate and would be safe to use.